# Import CSV multiple ranges and headers

Tags: r, excel, csv, import

I am trying to import the following file with two repeated sections of data to extract. The first set begins with unused header (line 5) and real header beginning with "ES" line 5). The next section of data begins with unused header (line 13) and real header beginning with "LU" (line 14) and more variable names. There are many of these files and in each there are different numbers of EU and LS sections of varying length. I need to extract the LS and EU data to separate dataframes. Unfortunately, the files are "as is" off of a sensor array and I can't change that and would prefer not to do all this in excel but may have to. In the real files there may be hundreds of these rows for each EU and LS set.

I have tried to adapt the following code to index EU sections and would then extract that and clean it up and then would have done the same on the LS sections but I did not even get this to work. Part of the reason is that EU was in both header rows. I did see code using perl scripts but have never used that language.

```
lns = readLines("lake1.txt")
idx = grepl("EU", lns)
df = read.table(text=lns[!idx])
wd = diff(c(which(idx), length(idx) + 1)) - 1
df$label = rep(lns[idx], wd)
```

I was not sure the best way to add a CSV file example but here it is...

```
Garbage Text 1,,,,,,,,
Garbage Text 2,,,,,,,,
Garbage Text 3,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
INTTIME ('sec'),SAMPLE ('sec'),ES_DARK ('uW/cm^2/nm'),ES_DARK ('uW/cm^2/nm'),ES_DARK ('uW/cm^2/nm'),CHECK (''),DATETAG (NONE),TIMETAG2 (NONE),POSFRAME (NONE)
ES,DELAY,344.83,348.23,351.62,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,0.35441789,-0.00060208,0.10290995,87,2017015,10:42:39,1
0.032,0,-0.36023974,-0.22242269,-0.09639,109,2017015,10:42:40,10
0.032,0,0.07552711,0.01524224,-0.16756855,91,2017015,10:42:48,41
,,,,,,,,11304
,,,,,,,,11312
,,,,,,,,
INTTIME ('sec'),SAMPLE ('sec'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),CHECK (''),DATETAG (NONE),TIMETAG2 (NONE),POSFRAME (NONE)
LU,DELAY,344.37,347.75,351.13,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,0.02288441,0.02891912,0.03595322,53,2017015,10:42:38,2
0.032,0,-0.00014323,0.00024047,0.00001585,212,2017015,10:42:38,6
0.032,0,0.00114258,0.00091736,-0.0000495,16,2017015,10:42:39,9
0.032,0,0.00020744,0.0004186,0.00027721,118,2017015,10:42:40,16
,,,,,,,,11310
,,,,,,,,
INTTIME ('sec'),SAMPLE ('sec'),ES ('uW/cm^2/nm'),ES ('uW/cm^2/nm'),ES ('uW/cm^2/nm'),CHECK (''),DATETAG (NONE),TIMETAG2 (NONE),POSFRAME (NONE)
ES,DELAY,344.83,348.23,351.62,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,56.7600789,59.43147464,62.83968564,186,2017015,10:42:38,3
0.032,0,56.27202003,59.52654061,62.86815706,29,2017015,10:42:38,4
,,,,,,,,11309
,,,,,,,,11311
,,,,,,,,
INTTIME ('sec'),SAMPLE ('sec'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),LU ('uW/cm^2/nm/sr'),CHECK (''),DATETAG (NONE),TIMETAG2 (NONE),POSFRAME (NONE)
LU,DELAY,344.37,347.75,351.13,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,-0.00011611,-0.00039544,-0.00014584,3,2017015,10:42:42,20
0.032,0,-0.00032394,-0.00020563,-0.00020383,229,2017015,10:42:46,39
```

This is what the two dataframes should look like in the end:

Dataframe 1

```
ES,DELAY,344.83,348.23,351.62,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,0.35441789,-0.00060208,0.10290995,87,2017015,10:42:39,1
0.032,0,-0.36023974,-0.22242269,-0.09639,109,2017015,10:42:40,10
0.032,0,0.07552711,0.01524224,-0.16756855,91,2017015,10:42:48,41
0.032,0,56.7600789,59.43147464,62.83968564,186,2017015,10:42:38,3
0.032,0,56.27202003,59.52654061,62.86815706,29,2017015,10:42:38,4
```

Dataframe 2

```
LU,DELAY,344.37,347.75,351.13,SUM,NONE,NONE,COUNTS
0.032,0,0.02288441,0.02891912,0.03595322,53,2017015,10:42:38,2
0.032,0,-0.00014323,0.00024047,0.00001585,212,2017015,10:42:38,6
0.032,0,0.00114258,0.00091736,-0.0000495,16,2017015,10:42:39,9
0.032,0,0.00020744,0.0004186,0.00027721,118,2017015,10:42:40,16
0.032,0,-0.00011611,-0.00039544,-0.00014584,3,2017015,10:42:42,20
0.032,0,-0.00032394,-0.00020563,-0.00020383,229,2017015,10:42:46,39
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got to the example output. Why weren't lines 9-11 included in the output `ES` file, and where are the `0.512` values and the last line coming form in the output `LU` file?

Comment: I was shortening the output so it was not too long. Sorry I can add it in but wanted to limit how long the post was.

Comment: That's fine, just trying to make sure I understand. Also, did you intend to exclude the lines line 10-11 (`,,,,,,,,11309`)

Comment: yes. I also edited the output. I was not sure the best way to show the intended 2 separate dataframes and will fix that too. I am a bit new at some of these postings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can solve this with [`tidyverse`](http://tidyverse.org/) tools.

[`readr`](http://readr.tidyverse.org/) for reading/writing csv files

[`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) for data frame manipulation

[`stringr`](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/) for string manipulation

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_1 <- read_csv("test1.csv", col_names = FALSE, col_types = cols(.default = "c"), skip = 3)
```

First remove the rows with all values missing, or all but the last, and rows with the extra headers.

Then create a new column with the `ES` or `LU` values, otherwise *`NA`*, and then use `tidyr::fill` to fill down those values.

Then change the two columns with `NONE` to `DATE` and `TIME` because later we don't want two columns with the same name.

```r
df_2 <- df_1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(X1), !str_detect(X1, "INTTIME")) %>% 
  mutate(grp = if_else(X1 %in% c("ES", "LU"), X1, NA_character_)) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(grp, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(X7 = str_replace(X7, "NONE", "DATE"),
         X8 = str_replace(X8, "NONE", "TIME"))

df_2

#> # A tibble: 15 x 10
#>       X1    X2          X3          X4          X5    X6      X7       X8     X9   grp
#>  * <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#>  1    ES DELAY      344.83      348.23      351.62   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS    ES
#>  2 0.032     0  0.35441789 -0.00060208  0.10290995    87 2017015 10:42:39      1    ES
#>  3 0.032     0 -0.36023974 -0.22242269    -0.09639   109 2017015 10:42:40     10    ES
#>  4 0.032     0  0.07552711  0.01524224 -0.16756855    91 2017015 10:42:48     41    ES
#>  5    LU DELAY      344.37      347.75      351.13   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS    LU
#>  6 0.032     0  0.02288441  0.02891912  0.03595322    53 2017015 10:42:38      2    LU
#>  7 0.032     0 -0.00014323  0.00024047  0.00001585   212 2017015 10:42:38      6    LU
#>  8 0.032     0  0.00114258  0.00091736  -0.0000495    16 2017015 10:42:39      9    LU
#>  9 0.032     0  0.00020744   0.0004186  0.00027721   118 2017015 10:42:40     16    LU
#> 10    ES DELAY      344.83      348.23      351.62   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS    ES
#> 11 0.032     0  56.7600789 59.43147464 62.83968564   186 2017015 10:42:38      3    ES
#> 12 0.032     0 56.27202003 59.52654061 62.86815706    29 2017015 10:42:38      4    ES
#> 13    LU DELAY      344.37      347.75      351.13   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS    LU
#> 14 0.032     0 -0.00011611 -0.00039544 -0.00014584     3 2017015 10:42:42     20    LU
#> 15 0.032     0 -0.00032394 -0.00020563 -0.00020383   229 2017015 10:42:46     39    LU
```

Now for each of `ES` and `LU` you can filter to just those records, then remove the new `grp` column, then use the first row as the column names, then remove those column header rows, and write to a new cleaned csv file.

```r
df_es <- df_2 %>% 
  filter(grp == "ES") %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(., .[1,]) %>% 
  filter(ES != "ES") %>% 
  write_csv("ES.csv")

df_es

#> # A tibble: 5 x 9
#>      ES DELAY    `344.83`    `348.23`    `351.62`   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS
#> * <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 0.032     0  0.35441789 -0.00060208  0.10290995    87 2017015 10:42:39      1
#> 2 0.032     0 -0.36023974 -0.22242269    -0.09639   109 2017015 10:42:40     10
#> 3 0.032     0  0.07552711  0.01524224 -0.16756855    91 2017015 10:42:48     41
#> 4 0.032     0  56.7600789 59.43147464 62.83968564   186 2017015 10:42:38      3
#> 5 0.032     0 56.27202003 59.52654061 62.86815706    29 2017015 10:42:38      4


df_lu <- df_2 %>% 
  filter(grp == "LU") %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  set_names(., .[1,]) %>% 
  filter(LU != "LU") %>% 
  write_csv("LU.csv")

df_lu

#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>      LU DELAY    `344.37`    `347.75`    `351.13`   SUM    DATE     TIME COUNTS
#> * <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 0.032     0  0.02288441  0.02891912  0.03595322    53 2017015 10:42:38      2
#> 2 0.032     0 -0.00014323  0.00024047  0.00001585   212 2017015 10:42:38      6
#> 3 0.032     0  0.00114258  0.00091736  -0.0000495    16 2017015 10:42:39      9
#> 4 0.032     0  0.00020744   0.0004186  0.00027721   118 2017015 10:42:40     16
#> 5 0.032     0 -0.00011611 -0.00039544 -0.00014584     3 2017015 10:42:42     20
#> 6 0.032     0 -0.00032394 -0.00020563 -0.00020383   229 2017015 10:42:46     39
```

Comment: That is the most elegant solution I have seen yet @austensen.

Thank you so much. I have not seen the tidyverse code used this way and will work to better understand how you did this and apply it in the future. 

Just when I thought I was getting good at R - I realize how little I really know.

Comment: @BillPerry Glad to hear it was helpful! Yeah, the tidyverse packages are really great. If you're looking to learn more, in addition to browsing through [tidyverse.org](http://tidyverse.org/), I would recommend reading [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html)